# Can Ubuntu fully utilize 64 processors and 64Gb RAM in an HPC (cluster): SGI Altix 3000?

Tags: video, blender, cluster

I have a chance to buy an older (2003) SGI Altix 3000 with 64 processors and 64GB RAM. Can ubuntu utilize all of those processors using programs such as blender, openshot (or other HD video apps) -, etc... or would I have to use a custom cluster/hpc distro? It was originally put together to run Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

The SGI Altix 3000 runs on IA64 processors. To cite an [answer on ServerFault](//serverfault.com/a/245547):

> Debian is [still kicking out ia64](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/6.0.0/ia64/iso-cd/) releases. If you're comfortable with Ubuntu, you'll find Debian quite familiar. With some apt repository tweaking, you'll be able to get similar package versions as well.

I don't see why it wouldn't be able to make use of all the processors and RAM. The Linux kernel easily runs on 256 CPU cores¹ and 1 TiB of memory² without changes to the source code. The default configuration may need a few configuration tweaks though, since it's geared towards AMD64-based workstations.

¹ The configuration allows up to 4096 CPU cores.

² Assuming 64 bits of address length. On IA64 it supports up to 2 TiB.

Comment: Thanks David! Very kind of you to take the time to take a peek at this and dig up some information ;) As far as I can tell, my easiest route to use this as a renderfarm is to use cinelerra because it has a built-in renderfarm feature. Otherwise I'm in over my head and investing more time than I want to in recompiling software etc, which is way over my head!